# Function constructor and functional programming

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand functional programming and function constructor.

First, going through function constructor, I went through [Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_function_constructors.htm)

I see they have used function constructor like this

```
var sum = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

console.log(sum(2, 6)); //This prints 8
```

So my first question is, this line here does not make sense to me.

```
('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
```

Here is the function taking strings as an argument or what? secondly, I know that the function declaration here is before ES6 but how can they still return something like this?

Secondly, I have been trying to do functional programming, so I am uploading a picture on the web and doing something like this

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image).reader.onload = e => {
  console.log(e)
}
```

but this is throwing **type error**, while something like this absolutely works

```
 let reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image);
 reader.onload = e => {
   console.log(e)
 }
```

Question: Can someone please explain my function constructor and help me why the above line of code is throwing an error?

Comment: `var sum = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');` ... is the same as ... `var sum = function(a, b) { return a + b; }` - not sure what you mean by *Here is function taking strings as an argument or what?*

Comment: @Bravo I got that but what I am trying to say is why they have used these here `''`  ?

Comment: For the first part of your question, MDN gives a very good explanation of what's happeneing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function The final argument of the function constructor is the function body

Comment: `reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image)` returns `undefined` ... and `undefined` doesn't happen to have your `reader` variable as a property (it has no properties at all)

Comment: @VarunBindal - because, the arguments passed to `new Function` are strings

Comment: I'm not sure what JS's "Function constructor" has to do with functional programming. Also, actually doing this is frowned upon, and with good reason (look up why `eval` is deprecated/discouraged - using `new Function(...)` in this way is basically the same as `eval`).

Comment: @Bravo No it doesn't return undefined. rather it returns something like this `FileReader {readyState: 1, result: "", error: null, onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, …}
error: null
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: ƒ (e)
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
readyState: 2
result: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCcUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAIAcAmcAFHFrNU43ZUU0VEIzY3dJU283bVZlHAIoAGJGQk1EMDEwM..`

Comment: @VarunBindal well, if you don't pass strings to `new Function()` then you have to have the actual *variables*. Think about it - you want to be constructing functions that will likely be invoked elsewhere, so you can't give them variables you currently possess, if you want to call them with different ones. Hence, you give strings that will define the name of the parameters and you will need to refer to them back by name. If you try to do `new Function(a, b, "return a + b")` then how are you to know `a` is a parameter, when JS will just look up its current value?

Comment: @RobinZigmond none of what's in this question is really related to functional programming. Aside from there being functions, I guess.

Comment: The reason that `reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image).reader.onload` does not work but the one with the enter works is because JS [automatically inserts semicolons](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/). So the one with the new line is `reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image);reader.onload`. If `readAsDataURL` returns a reader (documentation does not say) then you can chain like so: `reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.image).onload`

Comment: @vlaz Not sure what you mean by *you have to have the actual variables*. **Think about it - you want to be constructing functions that will likely be invoked elsewhere, so you can't give them variables you currently possess**. I can do something like this `let a = "apple" let b = "anything" function something (a, b) {
return a + b }
console.log(something(2,4))` which will still print 6 and if I do `console.log(something(3,4))` it will print 7. I am sure you are definitely trying to explain something else which isn't making sense to me. Can you please try in length in answer section?

Comment: Right you can do that. But when constructing a function through `new Function` and you pass `a` and `b` when they aren't strings, then JS doesn't treat them any different to other function calls, so the values will be resolved and put in their place. You'd be calling `new Function("apple", "anything", "return a + b")`

Comment: @VarunBindal - so `let x = reader.readAsDataUrl(this.stage.image); console.log(x === undefined);` logs `false` for you?